# Can ifrits be royalty?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, lore

I've been doing some digging for lore purposes, and possible side quests for my friends in our current game. i was wondering if it is possible for ifrits to have a kingdom or city to themselves. And if so, what king of Monarchy would they have? sultans? kings?

So far i have found they are mostly independent in human cities or otherwise in tribes. But just was a thought for lore sake and some interesting quests in a ifrit city!

Comment: @KorvinStarmast While similar in name to the [efreet](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/genie/efreeti), the [ifrit](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-ifrit) is a distinct race in in *Pathfinder.*

Comment: Is this a game set in Golarion or in your own world? Disclosing the relevant setting is critical for lore questions.

Comment: @HeyICanChan oops, thanks, pathfinder only, it's a different creature.

Answer (score 11):

**It's your game world, make it up**

You are planning a campaign with your friends.  They seem interested in this idea. You already are planning on building the city, campaign plot, etc. your self.  You have no reason to use Golarion lore, since you are not playing in Golarion.

For many D&D/Pathfinder things, there is lore in each particular system iteration itself, which dictates setting material independent of campaign.  The relevant Core lore here states:

> Ifrits are most often born into human communities, and rarely form societies of their own.

which indicates that an Ifrit kingdom should be rare and unusual.

> Humans whose ancestry includes beings of elemental fire such as efreet, ifrits are a passionate and fickle race.

Which indicate that Ifrit breed true, and what you are looking for is actually possible.

> Ifrits are usually lawful neutral or chaotic neutral, with a few falling into true neutrality.

Which informs what kind of governments make sense, depending on how you run alignment.

But outside of this, you have basically no guidance.  Whether or not this is reasonable is up to you and how you culture Ifrits in your campaign.

Answer (score 2):

Royalty is typically decided by two things, those who were born into royalty, and those who seized power when it was available for the taking and are now king. The latter normally do so through some kind of coup, but its just as reliable a method as becoming royalty as any. If your Ifrit that you're conceptualizing was the son of a person who was either born into royalty or took royalty into his own hands, he/she is technically a prince/princess.

So I'd say yes. Since Ifrit bloodlines are genetic they can also likely skip generations if you follow the rules of common genetics, the possibility is definitely there. They could be a fear inspiring leader or a benevolent one, all of that is up to you, it's your world, do with it what you will, and how you will.

Answer (score -5):

Outside of Pathfinder rules, here's a picture of a Djinn king. So, culture and mythology are on your side.

http://bodley30.bodley.ox.ac.uk:8180/luna/servlet/detail/ODLodl~23~23~96808~137101:Demons--the-black-king-of-the-djinn

Comment: The Ifrit are not Djinni.  Some Ifrit are Genie kin, i.e. descendant from the Efreet, but that, if anything, makes them less likely to be rulers, as their Genie ancestors have a habit of ruling over the lesser creatures of Fire.